# Index Help - Plan has 2 index-scans, query is slow & high-wait

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning, execution-plan

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJpfNCsJl

The query above is identified as "expensive" and "slow" by monitoring tools, and I feel it could use some indexing help, but I'm not completely sure how.  `sp_BlitzIndex` doesn't give a lot of concrete recommendations for it, and of course Plan Explorer only identifies the problem just as I said it, which is those 2 nasty **scans**.

Does anybody have a recommendation on what index(es) to add that could help turn those scans into seeks, to squeeze some better efficiency out of this query?  Thanks!

Comment: I see a large number of "Actual Number of Rows 0" - is that an artifact of Paste The Plan or did you really not get any results when you ran this?

Comment: @Forrest correct, that comes from me running the query with a parameter value that doesn't actually net any data... I could try it again with another value to try to get actual rows > 0, but I'm not sure if that would help the index tuning analysis/advice.

Comment: If you're getting 0 rows back but estimating 5.25 million, that's a problem and I'd wager that there either aren't very good stats for that parameter, in this case looks like membered and registryid. There is a merge join that leads to a hash join (impossible to tell from obfuscated plan the base tables) where most of your problems are. Can't see if there are any predicates pushed down there or not...

Comment: Are these physical tables or views ? I am not sure why query chose serial plan a parallel plan would help here